# Replace function not working as expected with Dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I'm reading a dask dataframe:

```
ddf = dd.read_csv({...}, dtype='object')
```

Next, I'm trying to replace commas with dots, so values can injected in a SQL DB as floats.

```
ddf = ddf.replace(",", ".")
```

However, when I'm call `ddf.to_sql({...})` my code is returning `ValueError: Unable to parse string "2,0" at position 8`, which suggests that the replace function is not working as expected. Why is this the case? Is there another way to replace commas with dots in Dask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regex here (right now you're replacing a single-character string ","):

```
ddf = ddf.replace("[,]", ".", regex=True)
```